# Is voting ever locked for questions/answers?

Tags: support, voting, closed-questions, locked

I just noticed I was able to vote on a question that was closed.

I found that a bit strange. Is there any time when you can't vote on a question/answer?
i.e. does it ever get locked also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't vote if the post is locked. That's different from just being closed. When it's closed you cannot add an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't vote on a question that's been locked. Try voting on any question thats been migrated and you'll see. (Even though it says [Closed] it's actually locked). You can still vote on closed questions.